# Can't get InnerBand CoreData framework to work

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, frameworks

I'm trying to get the InnerBand framework to work. Here is a link if you dont know it:
https://github.com/ZaBlanc/InnerBand

I followed the readme on the github page as well as the tutorial on the creators site, nevertheless I get an error at the very first command.

```
Car *myCar = [Car create];
```

Xcode only says "No known class method for selector 'create'".

What I've done so far:

-created a .xcdatamodeld file, added entity (Car) and attributes and saved it as NSManagedObject subclass.

-imported the following into the project and wrote the following into the .pch file.

```
#import "IBCoreDataStore.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "Car.h"
```

I'm relatively new to programming, so what am I missing? Should the Car.h class extend the InnerBand framework in some way to make the methods (like create) available?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I verified this for you.

You need to

```
#import "NSManagedObject+InnerBand.h"
```

to use `create` method.

These are the methods included in that category extension:

```
// CREATION

+ (id)create;
+ (id)createInStore:(IBCoreDataStore *)store;

// QUERY

+ (NSArray *)all;
+ (NSArray *)allForPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate;
+ (NSArray *)allForPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate orderBy:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)ascending;
+ (NSArray *)allOrderedBy:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)ascending;
+ (NSArray *)allInStore:(IBCoreDataStore *)store;
+ (NSArray *)allForPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate inStore:(IBCoreDataStore *)store;
+ (NSArray *)allForPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate orderBy:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)ascending inStore:(IBCoreDataStore *)store;
+ (NSArray *)allOrderedBy:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)ascending inStore:(IBCoreDataStore *)store;

+ (id)first;
+ (id)firstWithKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSObject *)value;

+ (id)firstInStore:(IBCoreDataStore *)store;
+ (id)firstWithKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSObject *)value inStore:(IBCoreDataStore *)store;

// DELETE/DESTROY

+ (void)destroyAll;
+ (void)destroyAllInStore:(IBCoreDataStore *)store;

- (void)destroy;
```